# UITableViewRowAction background color overlap issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios10, iphone-6, uitableviewrowaction

For some rows in tableview last UITableViewRowAction's background color collapse with previous buttons. Also this issue happens only iPhone 6/6S.

[image]

Comment: for me it is working fine. why it overlapped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure you are passing rounded value for the tableview's 'rowHeight' property. When we calculate row height dynamically based on text this issue will occur.